# Why did Rama tell Lakshmana that "your father" is dead and not "our father"?

Tags: ramayana, rama, lakshmana

Bharata told to Rama and Lakshmana that King Dasaratha died. Immediately, Rama tells Lakshmana that *your father* is dead. But Rama is also a son of Dasaratha.

What is the reason behind Rama telling Lakshmana that *your father* is dead? Why didn't he say '*our father* has died' or just '*father* has died?'

Comment: I think Periyavachan Pillai talks about this in his Tanishloki.

Comment: @Mani--It is in valmiki Ramayan only. I have read in the book Vedaraman. Will give the chapter number tomorrow.

Comment: @Surya---May be but I read in Vedaraman book.

Comment: When God Sri Rama, "himself", says something, there does not exist any  room for  speculations.When wise people, across the world, donot speculate on the word of God through the Sages, which is called as Vedas, God Sri Rama’s words, also - donot leave any room for speculation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Valmiki Ramayana, [Ayodhya Kanda, Sarga 103, Sloka 15](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga103/ayodhyasans103.htm#Verse15), Rama says पित्रा हीनोऽसि लक्ष्मण meaning "O Lakshmana, You became fatherless."

Following explanation is based on Brahmasri Chaganti Koteswara Rao's [speech](https://youtu.be/HH5PQS6ni88?t=7272) on Ramayana.

> If father dies, elder brother is considered to be equivalent to or
>   taking the position of father. Since Dasaratha died Rama has to treat
>   Lakshmana as a father. Though the exile is only for Rama, Lakshmana
>   came along with him to forest (even though not necessary) and
>   Lakshmana is doing service to Rama. So Rama is not able to be a good
>   father-like in caring about Lakshmana. But instead Lakshmana is
>   serving Rama and taking care of him like a father.

Rama is seeing a father in Lakshmana even though Dasaratha died. So that is why Rama said to Lakshmana "*you* became fatherless."

Comment: @SwiftPushkar See my answer given below for the scriptural source u are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

The answer given by @Student is correct.

However, **let me add in this answer, the Scriptural verses which says that an elder brother is equivalent to the father when the later dies**.It will also answer the following question raised by @SwiftPushkar:

> You have mentioned this "If father dies, elder brother is considered
>   to be equivalent to or taking the position of father." Which Hinduism
>   scripture states this law?

**Source**-Manu Smriti, Chapter 9.

**Context**-Deciding the shares of parental property after  death of the father .

> 9.108. As a father (supports) his sons, so let the eldest support his younger brothers, and let them also in accordance with the law behave
>   towards their eldest brother as sons (behave towards their father).
>
> 9.110. **If the eldest brother behaves as an eldest brother (ought to do), he (must be treated) like a mother and like a father**; but if he
>   behaves in a manner unworthy of an eldest brother, he should yet be
>   honoured like a kinsman.

[image]

Another verse(from Manu smriti) which says(indirectly) that an elder brother is like(equivalent to) a father to the younger brother is this:

> 9.57. The wife of an elder brother is for his younger (brother) the wife of a Guru; **but the wife of the younger is declared (to be) the
>   daughter-in-law of the elder**.

[image]